# Integral solutions to $Ax = y$

Tags: linear-algebra

What is a necessary and sufficient condition that the solutions of $Ax = y$ be integers whenever the components of $y$ are integers, given that the elements of $A$ are integers?

When $A$ is invertible and $|A|=1$ the inverse $A^{-1}$ expressed in terms of cofactors and the determinant gives sufficiency. But what is the way to handle the more general case.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A$ is not invertible and that $Ax=y$. Since $A$ is not invertible, $A$ has an nontrivial nullspace. That is, there exists a nonzero $z$ in the nullspace of $A$. It follows that $$A(\lambda z+x)=A\lambda z+Ax=\lambda Az+Ax=0+Ax=Ax=y\tag{1}$$ for every scalar $\lambda$.

Now, further suppose that $A$ and $y$ have integer entries. Seeking a contradiction, suppose that $Av=y$ implies $v$ has integer entries. Then $(1)$ implies that $\lambda z+x$ has integer entries for every scalar $\lambda$. But $z$ has a nonzero integer entry $z_k$ so taking $\lambda=\pi$ gives a contradiction.

Hence there exists no noninvertible integer matrix $A$ and integer $y$ such that $Av=y$ implies $v$ is integer.